# Telnet in Monterey

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, monterey

I'm struggling to open telnet in Monterey through the browser.
I can manually telnet using the command and works perfectly; same if I setup iTerm2 as the default app but I'd really like to use the native Terminal. In the preferences I have the "New windows open with default profile" selected.

The error I'm getting is:

```
[Command not found: telnet]

[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

Comment: What `telnet` program is installed on your Mac (i.e. is it from homebrew, or something else), and *where* is it (i.e. if you run `type -a telnet`, what does it show)?

Comment: Indeed I installed it from homebrew. Output from type -a telnet is: 
telnet is /opt/homebrew/bin/telnet
telnet is /usr/local/bin/telnet
telnet is /opt/homebrew/bin//telnet

Comment: When you say “open telnet through the browser” is it safari and what sort of link or page is being navigated?

Answer (score 3):

Install `telnet` and add its installation directory to the Launch Services PATH:

```
sudo launchctl config user path "$(sysctl -n user.cs_path):$(dirname "$(command -v telnet)")"
```

This assumes that `launchctl getenv PATH` returns an empty string and that `telnet` is in the shells PATH.

##### Explanation

Applications can register their ablility to handle the `telnet://` URL Scheme with [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-CIHFEEAD), like `Terminal.app` has done in `/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>telnet URL</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>telnet</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
```

But `telnet` is no longer provided by macOS, so we have to install it ourselves, by `brew install telnet` or by following a guide of [How to Get Telnet](https://osxdaily.com/2018/07/18/get-telnet-macos/).

However, even after the installation it still might fail:

```
$ open telnet://localhost:23

[Command not found: telnet]

[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

It fails when the Launch Services PATH does not contain the `telnet` installation directory. The current value of this PATH can be printed with `launchctl getenv PATH`; if empty, the default is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` as seen by `sysctl -n user.cs_path`. Those directories are all under [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) so we could/should not have installed `telnet` to any of them.

We fix this by adding the `telnet` installation directory to the PATH with `launchctl config user path <value>`, see launchctl(1).

##### Undo

Reset the Launch Services PATH to default with:

```
sudo launchctl config user path ""
```

Comment: Homebrew installs to `/opt/homebrew` on ARM, and puts the binaries into `/opt/homebrew/bin`. A generic solution could use `brew --prefix` to find the installation directory.

Comment: It might not be installed with homebrew, so perhaps `$(dirname $(command -v telnet))`

Comment: @nohillside does homebrew not symlink /usr/local/bin/telnet on ARM?

Comment: No, it symlinks to /opt/homebrew/bin on ARM. It always links to `$(brew --prefix)/bin` though.

Answer (score 1):

`telnet` is no longer included by default in macOS installs, as it is a rarely-used and extremely insecure protocol. When you do have a need for it, you can install it by using one of the standard macOS software port repositories, such as **[Homebrew](https://brew.sh)**, or by compiling and installing it yourself from source. **[gnu netutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/)** contains one such implementation.

If you're able to simply run `telnet` from inside Terminal, then that means that you've already installed it somewhere and it's able to be located via your `PATH` environment variable. You can use `which telnet` to see where it lives. You can then use that explicit path for your Terminal profile settings.

**UPDATE:**

Here are steps to configure Terminal to run `telnet` at startup.

1. Open Terminal.
2. Navigate to Terminal > Preferences.
3. Choose the Profiles tab.
4. In your default profile, click the Shell tab.
5. In the field that says "Run command:" replace the existing command with the absolute path to telnet. In your case, that would be `/opt/homebrew/bin/telnet`.
6. You may optionally enable or disable the "Run inside shell" option according to your tastes.

Comment: I wasn't expecting a copy/paste. If you read what I wrote you would then know that I have telnet running but there's a problem with the native terminal app while trying to launch it in a new window.

Comment: @DefaultVLAN Since you didn’t bother to read the rest of my answer, I’ll ask explicitly: What does `which telnet` say?

Comment: I did read it all, it says /opt/homebrew/bin/telnet

Comment: @DefaultVLAN Great. And so did you try passing that explicit path to Terminal?

Comment: Its in my $PATH variable, trying to figure out where's missing.

Comment: Terminal doesn't use $PATH. Use the explicit path.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @DefaultVLAN `PATH` is partly set up by various shell initialization scripts. Anything that doesn't run under a shell won't have that setup, and hence will generally have a much more basic `PATH`. So if you use Terminal -> shell -> `telnet`, it'll look in places like `/opt/homebrew/bin`, but if you use Terminal -> `telnet` (no shell in between), it won't.

Comment: OK, perfect thats what I was thinking, now im completely lost in zsh how to do it because of Apple's implementations.

Comment: @DefaultVLAN I've amended my answer with explicit instructions.

Comment: @pion, I understand but that way will always run independently of what I want to do, and even then it won't work if I try to launch it in a new shell through the browser. In safari I need to click on a button which will run an instance and that will launch a shell that executes "telnet ipaddress port" it just won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Got it working.

Only solution that finally fixed it was to disable SIP, disable authenticated root, mount the root partition, copying telnet to /usr/bin and then committing the changes to the partition.

Telnet works like a charm now.

Comment: If you just install it in /usr/local/bin, then you won't need to bypass any of the system security.